# Implement a String in a separator Swift3

Tags: xcode, string, swift3, separator, let

I have a question. I work on a app with currencies and i want to put the correct currency symbol automatically in the let applcation to trim the complete string. First i have this code snipped :

```
let firstPriceTrimmed = firstPrice.components(separatedBy: "€").flatMap { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.last
```

Now my code ist look like :

```
switch sideIDS {
    case 6, 8, 9, 10, 12:
        var current = "€"
        let firstPriceTrimmedNew = firstPriceTrimmed?.components(separatedBy: String(current)) { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.first
    case 7:
        var current = "£"
        let firstPriceTrimmedNew = firstPriceTrimmed?.components(separatedBy: String(current)) { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.last
    case 11:
        var current = "₹"
        let firstPriceTrimmedNew = firstPriceTrimmed?.components(separatedBy: String(current)) { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.last
    default:
        XCTFail()
    }
```

But it didn't work. XCode put the message "Cannot invoke 'components' with an argument list of type '(separatedBy: String?, (_) -> _)'. Whats wrong? I don't understand what XCode is wanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added `.flapMap` or any other closure with result of `components(separatedBy:)` inside all `cases` of `switch`.

```
let firstPriceTrimmedNew: String

switch sideIDS {
case 6, 8, 9, 10, 12:
    let current = "€"
    firstPriceTrimmedNew = firstPriceTrimmed?.components(separatedBy: current).flatMap { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.first
case 7:
    let current = "£"
    firstPriceTrimmedNew = firstPriceTrimmed?.components(separatedBy: current).flatMap { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.last
case 11:
    let current = "₹"
    firstPriceTrimmedNew = firstPriceTrimmed?.components(separatedBy: current).flatMap { String($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }.last
default:
    XCTFail()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But now i have another question. My problem is now, that i can't get the new information outside the case. The 'firstPriceTrimmedNew' variable is outside of the case deleted. Is it possible to get the information outside of the case? 'return firstPriceTrimmedNew' didn't work...

Comment: Do you have a solution that i get the information outside of the case?

Comment: @Saintz I already edited answer with it check that, declare `let firstPriceTrimmedNew: String` before the switch block and initialized it inside each case, check once again my edited answer